# Parse XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

This is what my XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <item>
    <date>May 2013</date>
    <html>http://www.link.to/html.html</html>
  </item>
```

I do this in the PHP and it kind of works

```
$file = '../modules/xml/nl-archive.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$string = '';
foreach($xml as $item){
    $string .= '<a href="'.$item->html .'" ><li>'.$item->date .'</li></a>';
}
```

Just trying to get the contents of the date tag and html tag to show up for each of the item tags. Been googling and tinkering, can't get it right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your XML to have a root with children like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <date>May 2013</date>
        <html>http://www.link.to/html.html</html>
    </item>
</items>
```

Php is just fine as you have it.

Comment: Ohhhh! I know that `simplexml_load_file()` usually just loads up the root tag so I thought it wouldn't matter if I had a root or not. Makes total sense now. thanks so much!